# Quicksort does not work with array bigger than 100

Tags: java, stack-overflow, quicksort

I have been trying to implement a normal non hybrid quicksort algorithm an d it works for arrays up to about 100 fields in size. I get the exception "stack-overflow" with most of you are probably familiar with. Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Quicksort {

    public int[] zahlenliste;

    public Quicksort(int[] zahlenliste) {
        sort(zahlenliste);
    }

    public void sort(int[] zahlenliste) {

        if (zahlenliste == null || zahlenliste.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        this.zahlenliste = zahlenliste;

        quickSort(0, zahlenliste.length - 1);
    }

    public void quickSort(int begin, int end) {
        if (begin >= end) {
            return;
        }
        int lower = begin;
        int higher = end;

        // Choose a pivot
        // int pivot = zahlenliste[lower + (higher - lower) / 2];

        int pivot = zahlenliste[lower + (higher - lower) / 2];

        while (lower <= higher) {
            while (zahlenliste[lower] < pivot) {
                lower++;
            }
            while (zahlenliste[higher] > pivot) {
                higher--;
            }
            if (lower < higher) {
                swap(zahlenliste, lower, higher);
            }

            lower++;
            higher--;
        }

        if (begin < higher) {
            quickSort(begin, lower);
        }

        if (lower < end) {
            quickSort(lower, end);
        }

    }

    public static int[] swap(int[] zahlenliste, int begin, int end) {
        int temp = zahlenliste[begin];
        zahlenliste[begin] = zahlenliste[end];
        zahlenliste[end] = temp;
        return zahlenliste;

    }

}
```

I know there are quicksort implementations where you choose a more fitting pivot by the median-three method or use insertion sort with lists smaller than 10. However I want to implement all of those an compare them on huge arrays. So it would be nice if anyone had a solution to get the simple quicksort to sort bigger arrays.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No it is something that I am working on myself. I've tested it further. After 30 elements I already get the "stack-overflow" exception. And the algorithm only wokrs correctly for about 10 to 20 elements. I honestly don't know what to do. When I google quicksort I get code that looks exactly like this only with the variables called differently.

Comment: Have you considered what happens when `zahlenliste[lower] == pivot` or `zahlenliste[higher] == pivot`? Also, the unconditional `lower++; higher--;` at the end of your main while loop looks suspicious. And also, look at the arguments to your two recursive calls.

Comment: I have changed the first call to quicksort(begin, higher). I have also tried every combination with and without the lower++ and the higher-- and also considered what happens when zahlenliste[lower] or zahlenliste[higher] == pivot. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. It doesnt crash but the list is just not sorted as it should be.

Comment: Rather than "trying every combination" it might be better to find a small array that fails and then step through the code with a debugger.  Quicksort is harder and more subtle than it seems at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes noted in comments

```
    public void quickSort(int begin, int end) {
        if (begin >= end) {
            return;
        }
        int lower = begin;
        int higher = end;

        int pivot = zahlenliste[lower + (higher - lower) / 2];

        while (lower <= higher) {
            while (zahlenliste[lower] < pivot) {
                lower++;
            }
            while (zahlenliste[higher] > pivot) {
                higher--;
            }
            if (lower <= higher) {                  // fix
                swap(zahlenliste, lower, higher);
                lower++;                            // fix
                higher--;                           // fix
            }
        }

        if (begin < lower-1) {                      // fix
            quickSort(begin, lower-1);              // fix
        }

        if (lower < end) {
            quickSort(lower, end);
        }
    }

    // fix (void)
    public void swap(int[] zahlenliste, int begin, int end) {
        int temp = zahlenliste[begin];
        zahlenliste[begin] = zahlenliste[end];
        zahlenliste[end] = temp;
    }
```

---

Example of a conventional Hoare partition based quick sort. It also only uses recursion on the smaller (or equal sized) partition, then iterates back to the top of the loop for the larger (or equal sized) partition:

```
    public static void qsort(long[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        while(lo < hi){
            int  md = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
            int  ll = lo-1;
            int  hh = hi+1;
            long p = a[md];
            long t;
            while(true){
                while(a[++ll] < p);
                while(a[--hh] > p);
                if(ll >= hh)
                    break;
                t     = a[ll];
                a[ll] = a[hh];
                a[hh] = t;
            }
            ll = hh++;
            // only use recursion on smaller partition,
            // then loop back for larger partition
            if((ll - lo) <= (hi - hh)){
                qsort(a, lo, ll);
                lo = hh;
            } else {
                qsort(a, hh, hi);
                hi = ll;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems a bit strange to have `if (lower <= higher)` and then swap the elements even when `lower == higher`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - it's a variation of Hoare partition scheme. I updated my answer to show a more conventional Hoare partition scheme which doesn't do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it. I am gonna have a look at the partition-quicksort as well. Thanks again!